# Eliminate duplicate value from a arraylist in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, equals

I have a number. 1st I found out the prime factor of this number. Say the number is 12, then prime factor [2,2,3].

Next I have to find out the other factor of this number like 12/2=6 ,[2,6] one factor. Second one is 12/3=4, [3,4] another factor.

2nd example , I considered another number =30. prime factor is[2,3,5]. Other factor is[2,15],[3,10],[5,6].

1 and the number itself is excluded.

Now I take an arraylist which consist of the prime factors of a given number. Then I iterate a loop and divide the number with there prime factor and get another factor.

Say `ArrayList abc={2,3,5}`

```
  if(abc.size()>=3){
        for(int i=0;i<abc.size();i++){
                abc1.add(abc.get(i));
                abc1.add(number / abc.get(i));


          }

        }
```

abc1 is another ArrayList for appending purpose. Now this solution work well when the abc arraylist consist of 3 or more than 3 different numbers like example 30. But it doesn't work well for a repeating numbers like example 12 where is the prime list 2 is a repeated number. I get the output [2,6],[2,6],[3,4].

To find out the repeated number from a list I write down this code block

```
for(int k=0;k<abc.size();k++){
        for(int j=k+1;j<abc.size();j++){
            if(abc.get(k).equals(abc.get(j))){
                System.out.println(abc.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

But how could I use this with previous code to eliminate one 2.

Comment: If the number is 36, prime factors are [2,2,3,3]. In this example, do you expect to get [6,6] as one of the "other" factors? I'm asking this because, I don't think your first code segment above does not handle such scenarios.

Comment: No It does not handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplicates you could use a `linkedHashSet` (to remove duplicates and maintain order or insertion) and then pass in that as the argument in the constructor of an `ArrayList`.

```
Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(s);
```

I hope I was able to answer your question, if I did not please let me know.

Comment: Note: You can use any Set you want, I just suggested the `linkedHashSet` as it is the most similar to the ArrayList.